# Creating a row in a relational table with EF 6.0

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

My database in SQL Server Management Studio looks like this:

[image]

In EF it looks like this:

[image]

So basically, when I add a `Bokningar` row I need the `RumsBokningar` table to contain the `Bokning_ID` of the `Bokningar` and the `Rum_ID` of the room. Here is my code:

```
var model = new HotellEntities();

model.Bokningar.Add(new Bokningar
                                {
                                    Antalpersoner = 2,
                                    Bokningsdatum = DateTime.Now,
                                    DatumFrån = dateTimeBokaFrån.Value,
                                    DatumTill = dateTimeBokaTill.Value,
                                    Namn = namnText.Text,                                      
                                });

model.SaveChanges();
```

This leads to a booking row being created but I need a `RumsBokningar` row to be created too...

`Bokningar` class:

```
public partial class Bokningar
{
        public Bokningar()
        {
            this.Rums = new HashSet<Rums>();
        }

        public int Bokning_ID { get; set; }
        public string Namn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Bokningsdatum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Antalpersoner { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DatumFrån { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DatumTill { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Rums> Rums { get; set; }
    }
```

`Rum` class:

```
public partial class Rums
{
        public Rums()
        {
            this.Bokningar = new HashSet<Bokningar>();
        }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int Rum_ID { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public Nullable<bool> Husdjur { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Pris { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Nummer { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Antalpersoner { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public virtual ICollection<Bokningar> Bokningar { get; set; }
}
```

There is no `RumsBokningar` class since that's just a navigation property.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A many-to-many relationship represented in objects is an object with a list of another object. (The other object also has a list of the first object) So when you create your `Bokningar` object, set it's `Rums` collection with a list of `Rums`. As below.

```
var bokningar new Bokningar
{
    Antalpersoner = 2,
    Bokningsdatum = DateTime.Now,
    DatumFrån = dateTimeBokaFrån.Value,
    DatumTill = dateTimeBokaTill.Value,
    Namn = namnText.Text,
    // Create your Rums here.
    Rums = new List<Rum>{ new Rum { Husdjur = true, ... } }                                      
});
```

Now one row for every `Rum` object will be inserted.

Likewise, a single `Rum` constains a list of `Bokningar` as below

```
var rum = new Rum
{
    Husdjur = true,
    // ...
    Bokningar = new List<Bokningar>{ new Bokningar { Antalpersoner = 2, ... } }
};

model.SaveChanges();
```